# DXL Scripting- Is there a way to check if the contents of an object are underlined?

Tags: fonts, ibm-doors

For each object in a module, I need to check if any of the contents are underlined.

Answer (score 0):

should be possible like this:

```
Regexp reUnderlined = regexp2 "\\\\ul"
string s = richTextNoOle( o."Object Text", false)
if reUnderlined (s) then {print "yes"} else { print "no"}
```

You will have to write a loop, of course, and you might want to examine more attributes than only Object Text.